# DUMPBIN /EXPORTS: why does it differ between debug and release binaries?

Tags: c++, dumpbin, unmanagedexports

I'm trying to understand how to interpret the output of `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS`, specifically the *Name* column:

| Binary | Ordinal | Hint | RVA | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x86 Debug | 1 | 0 | 00090B67 | ??0ImBitVector@@QAE@$$QAU0@@Z = @ILT+7010(??0ImBitVector@@QAE@$$QAU0@@Z) |
| x64 Debug | 1 | 0 | 000958ED | ??0ImBitVector@@QEAA@$$QEAU0@@Z = @ILT+2280(??0ImBitVector@@QEAA@$$QEAU0@@Z) |
| x86 Release | 1 | 0 | 00001C80 | ??0ImBitVector@@QAE@$$QAU0@@Z = ??0ImBitVector@@QAE@$$QAU0@@Z (public: __thiscall ImBitVector::ImBitVector(struct ImBitVector &&)) |
| x64 Release | 1 | 0 | 00001900 | ??0ImBitVector@@QEAA@$$QEAU0@@Z = ??0ImBitVector@@QEAA@$$QEAU0@@Z (public: __cdecl ImBitVector::ImBitVector(struct ImBitVector &&)) |

Here's what I've understood for the moment:

| Binary | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| Debug | entry point = some index in the ILT? (entry point again?) |
| Release | entry point = entry point again? (prototype/declaration) |

Is that just redundant information in the output or not at all?

More exactly,

- why is that name repeated after the equal sign?
- why is that encompassed with @ILT for debug binaries?

Comment: You can use the `undname.exe` (*undecorated name*) that comes with Visual Studio.  ILT means "import location table".

Comment: ILT = Incremental Linking Table, /INCREMENTAL is the default for the Debug build.  Dumpbin.exe knows how to use the .pdb file for a DLL, uses it to lookup the identifier of exported function.  Delete the .pdb file and run Dumpbin.exe again to see the difference.

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed, everyday I learn something new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done for the sake of incremental linking. As far as I know, Microsoft has never published exact details, but if you do a debug build with incremental linking disabled, the result looks the same as for a release build.

For example, let's start with nearly the simplest possible DLL:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) int trash(int) { return 0; }
```

If we do a normal debug build, with: `cl /LD /Zi trash.cpp`, the output from dumpbin /exports is:

```
1    0 00001A91 ?trash@@YAHH@Z = @ILT+2700(?trash@@YAHH@Z)
```

But if we change the build to: `cl /LD /Zi trash.cpp /link /incremental:no`, and do a dumpbin again, we get:

```
1    0 00001000 ?trash@@YAHH@Z = ?trash@@YAHH@Z (int __cdecl trash(int))
```

...just like a release build produces.

Although it's only a guess (as I said, I don't know of Microsoft having published any details) the basic idea here is to separate parts of the file that change more frequently from parts that change less frequently, so then the linker modifies the executable in an incremental link, it won't have to rewrite as much of the file, and/or the incremental link may succeed more often so it doesn't have to write a whole new executable as often. But as I said, that part's only a guess.

As to the redundancy in the output, I believe (but no longer have the right tools installed to confirm) that this is to deal with the possibility of exporting by ordinal. If you export by ordinal the exported name will be something like `@1`. But dumpbin can find the real name, so if you'd exported the function by ordinal, you might get output something on this order:

```
1    0 00001000 @1 = ?trash@@YAHH@Z (int __cdecl trash(int))
```

So what's on the left of the `=` is the exported ordinal, then after the equal gives the name that maps to, followed by the undecorated name.

But that's going from distant memories--exporting by ordinal was mostly a 16-bit Windows thing that's been (at least unofficially) deprecated for years (and for x64, I don't think it's supported any more at all).

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you for the explanations :)